# How to have full-height windows when the dock is on the bottom and centered?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I finally managed to put my dock on the bottom and centered. But now, it looks like this

[image: that]

What bothers me is that (for instance) my Firefox window is not on full-height and we see the wallpaper on the bottom on my screen. Is there a way for my windows to be on full-height automatically (kind of like this
[image: this]) ? (I would still like to see the dock).

I've been searching for a while now and I can't seem to find someone who did that..
Thanks for your help!